# textView resignFirstResponder not working

Tags: iphone

For iphone app make long text input we use UITextView. but how the keyboard return.
[textView resignFirstResponder] not working for UITextView.

Comment: Where are you using resignFirstResponder?

Comment: at this delegate method:- (void)textViewDidEndEditing:(UITextView *)textView
{
    [textView resignFirstResponder];
}

Answer (score 0):

Declare UITextViewDelegate protocol in your interface. then implement delegate method

```
 - (BOOL)textView:(UITextView *)textView shouldChangeTextInRange:(NSRange)range replacementText:(NSString *)text {

if([text isEqualToString:@"\n"]) {
    [textView resignFirstResponder];
    return NO;
}

return YES;
}
```

Comment: yes its right but In this code you make text = new line then its return.so if we give some lines in our text how we get it..when we give new line it return.

Comment: @Nimmi Actually you didn't connect UITextViewDelegate to filesOwner using the interface builder or you can set through programatically like textview.delegate=self; And also you can set the return key to Done from uitextview attribute inspector

Comment: You can put spaces between words by using space key and for new line also  and for next line you don't do anything it automatically starts from new line if it reaches at end of line or a lot of spaces

Comment: lots of space ...its not good solution...is there any way that give us new line...